# can't write unknown attribute `company_profile_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a set of users to a company_profile object. The idea is a user will create a company and then add more users to the company in various roles.

The company profile has an address object, and when I pull up the form on the new call I get this error:
"can't write unknown attribute `company_profile_id`"

company_profile -> new

```
<%= form_for(setup_companyProfile(@companyProfile), validate: true, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/address', :locals => {:f => address} %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
  belongs_to :company_profile
```

helper.rb

```
def setup_companyProfile(companyProfile)
    if(companyProfile.address.present? == false)
      companyProfile.address ||= Address.new
    end

    companyProfile
  end
```

company_profile.rb

```
class CompanyProfile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

company_profile_controller.rb

```
class CompanyProfileController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @companyProfile = CompanyProfile.new
  end

  def edit
    @companyProfile = CompanyProfile.find(current_user.company_profile_id)
  end

  def update
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `has_one` from the company-profile model... Rails expects there to be a `belongs_to :company_profile` on the `Address` model... and this `belongs_to` requires a column called `company_profile_id` on the `addresses` table... do you have that? If not - you will need to create a migration that adds it.